# Spring boot is not loading profile specific yaml or properties if set on EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot is not loading profile specific yaml or properties if set on EnvironmentPostProcessor.

Please help on how to properly initialize this profile.

Comment: How do you set the profile?

Comment: Programmatically at the end of  postProcessEnvironment, with env.setActiveProfiles("someProfile");